# How to import props into a function that is being rendered in a component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, blockchain

In a react DApp I can display a value from the Redux store inside my component main render function. But I don't know to pass it to a function that is being passed to the render main function. Everything I have tried fails.

Here is some code that is working. I would like to reuse it in other components.

We will focus on the token symbol.

**Actions.js;**

```
  export function tokenSymbolLoaded(symbol) {
    return {
      type: 'TOKEN_SYMBOL_LOADED',
      symbol
    }
  }
```

**Interactions.js;**

```
import {tokenLoadedSymbol} from './actions'

export const loadTokenSymbol = async (token, dispatch) => {
  const symbol = await token.methods.symbol().call()          
    console.log(symbol)
    dispatch(tokenSymbolLoaded(symbol))
    return symbol
}
```

**Selectors.js;**

```
const tokenSymbolLoaded = state => get(state, 'token.symbol')
export const tokenSymbolLoadedSelector = createSelector(tokenSymbolLoaded, tls => tls)
```

**Reducers.js;**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
    function token(state = {}, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
          case 'TOKEN_LOADED':
            return { ...state, loaded: true, contract: action.contract }
            case 'TOKEN_SYMBOL_LOADED':
            return { ...state, loaded: true, symbol: action.symbol}
          default:
            return state
        }
      }
```

**The component** *(removed unnecessary html);*

```
import {tokenSymbolLoadedSelector} from '../store/interactions'
    
    class MyTransactions extends Component {
      render() {
      
        return  (
                    <some html> {this.props.symbol} </some html>
                )
               }
    }
    
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return {
       symbol: tokenSymbolLoadedSelector(state)
     }
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyTransactions);
```

This code is working. Now I would like to reuse this symbol selector in other components of my DApp. But the other component is made of multiple function and this is where it's not working and I would like to understand why.

The non working code inside another component;

```
  import {
      priceChartLoadedSelector,
      priceChartSelector,
      tokenSymbolLoadedSelector
    } from '../store/selectors'
    
    const showPriceChart = (priceChart) => {
     
      return(
            <h4>{this.props.symbol}/ETH &nbsp; {priceSymbol(priceChart.lastPriceChange)} &nbsp; {priceChart.lastPrice}</h4>   
      )
    }
    
    class PriceChart extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
            <div >
              {this.props.priceChartLoaded ? showPriceChart(this.props.priceChart) : <Spinner />}
            </div>
        )
      }
    }
    
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {  
        priceChartLoaded: priceChartLoadedSelector(state),
        priceChart: priceChartSelector(state),
        symbol: tokenSymbolLoadedSelector(state),
      }
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PriceChart)
```

This is the error thrown:

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: Where is the error occurring? Do you have a stacktrace available that you can update into your question with?

Comment: The error occurs at {this.props.symbol}. What is stacktrace? is it the trace option in redux dev?

Comment: It's the output that generally accompanies errors in the console that tell you what functions were called and include line numbers. The "stack" represents the callstack, so when reading it you see it in reverse order of the calls, i.e. starting with the most recent and working backwards.

Comment: Pretty sure the issue is that `showPriceChart` is not a method of `PriceChart`, so it does not have access to `this.props`. You can pass the symbol as a parameter if you would rather keep them separate.

Comment: @lawrence-witt I have tried that const showPriceChart = (priceChart, symbol). I don't get an error like this but the symbol it no shown. it's undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, The reason your code is not working is you tried to call showPrice method out of your class component. if you called it. it might be called but you won't have the reference to `this` keyword. This is how you should write it. Besides hope, there exists a method called `priceSymbol`.

```
class PriceChart extends Component {

showPriceChart = (priceChart) => {
     
      return(
            <h4>{this.props.symbol}/ETH &nbsp; {priceSymbol(priceChart.lastPriceChange)} &nbsp; {priceChart.lastPrice}</h4>   
      )
    }

      render() {
        return (
            <div >
              {this.props.priceChartLoaded ? this.showPriceChart(this.props.priceChart) : <Spinner />}
            </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: The priceSymbol is working it's this.props.symbol that is causing the error

Comment: Of course, it is `this.props.symbol` that is why I wrote the code for you. I said priceSymbol exists because I didn't see it anywhere. but I know the problem is not with `priceSymbol` and it is with the `this.props.symbol`. and the above code fixes it

Comment: You tried to access props outside your class component. That is why `this.props.symbol` is not working.try the above code.

Comment: It<s telling me showPriceChart in undefined but symbol seams to pass

Comment: you didn't add  `this` keyword to showPriceCart. add it and let me know what it says

Comment: `{this.props.priceChartLoaded ? this.showPriceChart(this.props.priceChart) : <Spinner />}` write just like this

Comment: OMG Thank you so much. It's working and you helped me understand it